# Uniqueness of measure on quotient

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, quotient-spaces

I am trying to work through Serge Lang's book $SL_2$. On page 37, he considers the invariant measure on a quotient space.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with closed subgroup $K$. Let $\mu_G$ and $\mu_K$ denote respective Haar measures, where the latter is normalized to one. For a compactly supported function $f \in C_c(G)$ define
\begin{align*}
f^K(x) = \int_K f(xk) \; d\mu_K(k)
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that $f^K$ can be seen as a function on $G/K$ because $f^K(x) = f^K(xk)$ for all $k \in K$. 
Then Lang states, as a Theorem, that there is a *unique* invariant measure $\mu_{G/K}$ on the quotient $G/K$ such that for any $f \in C_c(G)$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{G/K} f^K \; d\mu_{G/K} = \int_G f \; d\mu_G
\end{align*}
Now here is my problem: In the proof, he states that uniqueness is obvious. I must be missing some obvious fact here, because I don't see where this is coming from. I can extend every indicator function on $G/K$ to a function on $G$, but that only gives me uniqueness on bounded sets, because the functions here all have compact support. What am I missing, how is the uniqueness obvious?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention and it is important here that, for simplicity, he assumes unimodular groups $K$ and $G$.

Comment: i mean, isn't an invariant measure itself unique? i thought haar measures are always unique. it's just a fact that that haar measure satisfies the second centered equation.

Comment: $G/K$ is not necessarily a group, is it? and personally, I know of Haar's theorem only on groups. So I am not sure whether one would call this measure a Haar measure?

Comment: ok good point. hopefully your answer is contained in one of the following two links: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21704/haar-measure-on-a-quotient https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14278/haar-measure-on-a-quotient-references-for

Comment: I already read that thread, but I dont think they answer the question on the uniqueness. I mean, in the end, it will be unique. I just want to know why. Lang's comment indicates to me there is an easy answer, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I gave two threads. if the answer is not in either, I'll spend some time and try to figure it out

Comment: Yes I have read through both before posting. The second specifically mentions further literature that I admit I haven't looked into. If noone knows an easy answer, I will do that.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get to it today

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not really so obvious...

First, at least in your quote from Lang, there're some imprecisions. Ok, for $G$ a (locally convex, Hausdorff, probably countably-based) topological group, and $H$ a closed subgroup, for *existence* of a measure on $H\backslash G$ such that
$$
\int_G f \;=\; \int_{H\backslash G}\int_H f(h\dot{g})\;dh\,d\dot{g}
$$
for $f$ compactly-supported continuous on $G$, it is necessary and sufficient that the modular function of $G$, restricted to $H$, is equal to the modular function of $H$. For compact $H$ (as was probably intended in your context, by "$K$"), this condition is automatic.

Apart from the condition on modular functions, existence and uniqueness will follow from the Riesz-Kakutani-Markov theorem (that functionals on continuous compactly-supported functions are given by integrals...), once we know that the averaging map $f\to f^H$ is a surjection from $C^o_c(G)$ to $C^o_c(H\backslash G)$. And this is true, but requires a little doing.

The above (and many related basic points) is very standard, so you should be able to find many alternative sources at the points where Lang becomes impatient or too terse.

EDIT: specific references: First, yes, indeed, this issue is often imbedded in a fairly sophisticated context, and can get lost. Some of my own notes aim to be minimalist, in a good way, in dealing with some of these things. E.g., in an old note on repns of totally disconnected groups http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/smooth_of_td.pdf there is a proof of this. Also, in both the physical book (by Cambridge Univ Press) and my (legal!) on-line version of my book "Modern Analysis of Automorphic Forms by Example", this and other things are dealt with at a level intended to be legitimate without going overboard. E.g., chapter 5 is "integration on quotients" in http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/current_version.pdf

Comment: I forgot to mention (and just edited it in) that he assumes both $G$ and $K$ to be unimodular, so the modular function wont play a big obvious role at least. Can you suggest a standard source that introduces this on a beginners level? Most of the books that I look into tend to be rather advanced to be honest. I am also only concerned with unimodular groups, so I have hope that this case severely eases the treatment somehow..

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into your references!